# Appending and Using JSON files with Javascript code on Ruby on Rails Pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js

I'm trying to use a JSON file to feed in data into Javascript code of a collapsible information tree. At the moment I have the hash values for the data values hard-coded into the Javascript code, but I would like to have it imported from a JSON hash. I was wondering if I would have to parse the JSON file into a Ruby Hash and use a Controller to feed data to the the Javascript application or if there was an easier way to attach the JSON file to the Javascript code that I already have. Thanks!

EDIT: I am also using the D3JS library to try and import the JSON file and turn it into values on the tree.

Comment: `const data = require('./path_to_json/file.json')`?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider making API endpoints(a controller action) that returns a JSON to an AJAX request to it. This would be worth doing, if the data you are fetching is dynamic.

If you think that the above would be an overkill, try the below described method instead.

Assuming you have set `@directory` (containing a ruby hash) in the action rendering the view you referred to, you can do the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var directory_tree = <%= raw(@directory.to_json) %>
</script>
```